# How to make xcode project forget SVN

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I have an xcode project that creates a framework, that had an SVN repository.  I have a working copy of the the project, but the repository no longer exists.

I have created a new workspace with a new SVN repository, and I add the old framework project to this workspace, (with the files in a folder that contains all the other workspace targets etc).

I want to have the new SVN repository contain all the files, but the old framework project insists on being associated with it's old repository.  How can I make it forget this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .svn folder in your old project.